# Javascript regular expression split

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string

```
 var str = "Here is some &text:also , here is &another:one"
 var myRegExp = /\b\s(\&){1}(\w)+(\:){1}(\w)+\s?\b/g
 str.match(myRegExp)
 //[" &text:also", " &another:one"]
```

Works as expected till now, the problem is with the splitting

```
str.split(myRegExp)
```

**Expectations:** ["Here is some" , ", here is"]
**Reality** ["Here is some", "&", "t", ":", "o", " , here is", "&", "r", ":", "e", ""]

What could be the reason for this ? I can extract my required array by looping over and splitting at the matches, isnt there any shortcut apart from that ?

Comment: Why are you escaping a colon?

Comment: Oh that works w/o escaping too thanks for the info, I was being careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `regex` engine is also including the `group` values into the result..use `(?:)`

So the regex to split would be

```
/\b\s(?:\&){1}(?:\w)+(?:\:){1}(?:\w)+\s?\b/g
```

Or there is no need of grouping it at all

```
/\b\s\&{1}\w+\:{1}\w+\s?\b/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the groupings or the `{1}` in the regex. Use:

```
var myRegExp = /\b\s&\w+:\w+\s?\b/g
```

Comment: I just posted a raw example, my actual regex has grouping though but for the given example groupings messed up the split, Thanks for the correction